# Without me, one can see nothing

Tags: riddle

> Without me, one can see nothing
> With too much of me, one can see nothing
> With enough of me, one can see everything
> Colors are thanks to me
> I am why things can see

What am I?

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Light?

Without me, one can see nothing

> Because it’s dark

With too much of me, one can see nothing

> Blinding light

With enough of me, one can see everything

> we can see with an appropriate amount of light

Colors are thanks to me

> Colours are wavelengths of light

I am why things can see

> We can see because of light

Comment: Too many smart people here! XD Yes, that is correct. I'm not good at making hard riddles, lol

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain%E2%80%93computer_interface#Vision) you can read something about seeing without light.

Comment: lol, is this why I got a thumbs down?